# How can I create a launch.json to use pipenv scripts?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pipenv

I have the following folder structure in a monorepo repository

```
/--.vscode
/--Services
  --/Service1
  --/Service2
  --/Service3
```

In each service, I am using pipenv with their commands like `dev`, `stg` or `prod` in order to execute the code.

The problem is when I want to debug code, that I only can use `pdb`.

The idea is to create a `.vscode/launch.json`, in order to execute that commands and use the vscode debug instead.

But I cannot build that configuration because I cannot set `pipenv run dev`

How can I set that configuration?

I set another configuration for a non-monorepo repository and works like this

```
{
// Use IntelliSense para saber los atributos posibles.
// Mantenga el puntero para ver las descripciones de los existentes atributos.
// Para más información, visite: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
{
"args": [],
"python.pythonPath": "${workspaceFolder}/venv/bin/python",
"name": "Run Server",
"type": "python",
"request": "launch",
"program": "${workspaceFolder}/wsgi.py",
"console": "integratedTerminal",
"justMyCode": true,
"env": {}
}
]
```

Comment: Have you added the environment path of pipenv to the setting.json ?

Comment: No I didn't, is it possible add any env path? in order to share settings.json in the repository?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the path to your Python interpreter, you can replace python with invoke in the "program" value in launch.json.

You can create a Python VS Code debugging configuration (launch.json) as follows :

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Start app",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "program": "path/to/virtualenv/invoke",
            "args": ["app.start"],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
        },
    ]
}
```